# maven ${user.home} not being resolved correctly

Tags: java, maven-2, properties

I've got the following line in my pom.xml:

```
<updateRepositoryURL>file:/${user.home}/.m2/repository/repository.xml</updateRepositoryURL>
```

and when I am attempting to use it within my program the resultant string is:

```
file:/c:Documents and Settings<myusername>/.m2/repository/repository.xml
```

where `<myusername>` is my user name funnily enough.

however it should be

```
file:/c:/Documents and Settings/<myusername>/.m2/repository/repository.xml
```

Does anyone out there have any ideas as to why it is not resolving properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What JDK and OS are you using? What is the value of %USERPROFILE% ?

Comment: had as little bit more of a look around.Turns out that it is resolving it somewhat right, its getting 
"file:/c:\Documents and Settings\<myusername>/.m2/repository/repository.xml"

using windows. and i believe that is the problem using the backslashes to delimit the path instead of forward slashes. thanks Pascal.

Comment: Yes, the problem comes form the backslashes. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be a bug in maven. I've bookmarked this [workaround](http://www.toolsforteams.com/roller/blog/entry/parameterized_user_home_for_maven) some time ago:

> I found a handy way to reference the
> Java system property `${user.home}`
> within a Maven build that supports
> Windows' ridiculous path name to
> home/profile directories:
>
> ```
> c:\Documents and Settings\foobar.
> ```
>
> The problem is, when using Maven, this
> parameterized property doesn't get
> passed through as one property value,
> but as three, because somewhere in the
> build Maven chokes on the spaces or
> back-slashes and interprets it as
> either three arguments:
>
> ```
> "c:\Documents", "and", "Settings\foobar"
> ```
>
> or treats the windows back-slash as an
> escape character and removes them so
> my parameterized user.home becomes:
>
> ```
> "c:Documents and Settingsfoobar"
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> However, on Windows XP, unless I set
> the user.home on the build path every
> time, the back-slash escaping or space
> issues cause the files to not be
> found.
>
> To fix it, add this profile to the
> `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml` file:
>
> ```
> <profile>
> <id>laptop-xp</id>
> <properties>
> <user.home>C:/Documents and Settings/${user.name}</user.home>
> </properties>
> </profile>
> ```
>
> Then add an appropriate entry to the
> activeProfiles:
>
> ```
> <activeProfile>laptop-xp</activeProfile>
> ```
>
> Now every user will be able to use the
> `user.home` property to reference
> their home path correctly on the
> Windows box.

Or, you're just another victim of this bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4787931. It's a very old bug (more than 6 years old) that affects all versions up till Java 1.6.x.

Comment: Thanks, That works but going to stil look for another solution at leads request. The link doesnt seem to work giving a 503 error.

Comment: +1 for the workaround, the alternative is to put the file somewhere else. You can override the localRepository in the settings to point to c:\.m2\repository or something else short and easy to find

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround could be to correct or produce the path via the **[Groovy GMaven plugin](https://books.sonatype.com/mcookbook/reference/ch02s03.html)**, similar to this groovy code:

```
System.setProperty(  
  'user.home.fixed',  
  System.getProperty('user.home').replaceAll( '\\\\', '/' )  )
```

Maybe one could even override `user.home`, but I am not sure if it would work. So using **`${user.home.fixed}`** everywhere instead of `${user.home}` should work then if executed in an early phase.